# GUI Java Application Compatible With Win7 But Not Compatible With Win10

Tags: java, windows, user-interface

I have built GUI java application with .exe setup file its work fine on any PC using windows 7 , but when i try to setup the program on windows 10 the graphic components(`jlabel,jtxtfield,...`) in some frames Overlap to each other
Here some pictures...
**Windows 7**
[image]

**Windows 10**
[image]

Comment: Do You have correct windows manifest for this EXE, wih WIn10 declaration? But generally such problems have logical reasons. What swing layout is used, maybe without layout ... broad problem

Answer (score 1):

It seems the **fonts** are problematic, got substituted, and sizes changed for that considerably. Check which fonts are used by the application and which are on the systems.

Think on using a free (Linux) font provided by your application, using `registerFont`:

```
InputStream fontIn = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/... .ttf");
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontIn);
GraphicsEnvironment ge = graphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
ge.registerFont(font);
```

[List of typefaces on Microsoft Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows)

Comment: did u mean maybe some fonts used in application are not declared in font factory on windows 10?